# Y-Axis label prefix for XY Amcharts

Tags: amcharts

I didn't find any solution how to add prefix/suffix for Y-Axis of XYAmChart. Seems like `labelFunction` are not supported for `valueAxes` in XY chart type. Any suggestions?

```js
   var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
   "type": "xy",
   "theme": "light",
   "dataDateFormat": "DD-MM-YYYY",
   "graphs": [
    {
     "id":"g8",
     "balloon":{
      "drop":true,
      "adjustBorderColor":false,
      "color":"#ffffff"
     },
     "bullet":"round",
     "bulletBorderAlpha":1,
     "bulletColor":"#FFFFFF",
     "bulletSize":5,
     "dashLength":0,
     "hideBulletsCount":50,
     "lineThickness":2,
     "lineColor":"#67b7dc",
     "title":"Store 8",
     "useLineColorForBulletBorder":true,
     "xField":"d-1-c2",
     "yField":"p-1-c2",
     "xAxis":"g8",
     "balloonText":"<span style='font-size:18px;'>[[d-1-c2]]</span><br>07/1/2017-12/31/2017"
    },
    {
     "id":"g8-copy1",
     "balloon":{
      "drop":true,
      "adjustBorderColor":false,
      "color":"#ffffff"
     },
     "bullet":"round",
     "bulletBorderAlpha":1,
     "bulletColor":"#FFFFFF",
     "bulletSize":5,
     "dashLength":15,
     "hideBulletsCount":50,
     "lineThickness":2,
     "lineColor":"#67b7dc",
     "title":"Store 8",
     "useLineColorForBulletBorder":true,
     "xField":"d-1-c1",
     "yField":"p-1-c1",
     "xAxis":"g8-copy1",
     "balloonText":"<span style='font-size:18px;'>[[d-1-c1]]</span><br>1/1/2017-6/29/2017"
    }
   ],
   "valueAxes": [
    {
     "id": "g8",
     "axisAlpha": 1,
     "gridAlpha": 1,
     "axisColor": "#b0de09",
     "color": "#b0de09",
     "dashLength": 5,
     "centerLabelOnFullp": true,
     "position": "bottom",
     "type": "date",
     "minp": "DD-MM-YYYY",
     "markPeriodChange": false,
     "labelFunction": function(value, valueText) {
       return "prefix:" + valueText;
     }
    },
    {
     "id": "g8-copy1",
     "gridAlpha": 0,
     "axisAlpha": 1,
     "centerLabelOnFullp": false,
     "position": "bottom",
     "offset": 40,
     "type": "date",
     "minp": "DD-MM-YYYY",
     'markPeriodChange': false,
     "labelFunction": function(value, valueText) {
       return "prefix:" + valueText;
     }
    }
   ],
   "dataProvider": [
    {
     "d-1-c2":"01/01/2017",
     "p-1-c2":"5684.6400"
    },{
     "d-1-c2":"01/02/2017",
     "p-1-c2":"6468.9600"
    },{
     "d-1-c2":"01/03/2017",
     "p-1-c2":"9032.7600"
    },{
     "d-1-c2":"01/04/2017",
     "p-1-c2":"6385.9200"
    },{
     "d-1-c2":"01/05/2017",
     "p-1-c2":"10087.3900"
    },{
     "d-1-c2":"01/06/2017",
     "p-1-c2":"6136.3300"
    },
    {
     "d-1-c1":"01/07/2017",
     "p-1-c1":"4659.7000"
    },{
     "d-1-c1":"01/08/2017",
     "p-1-c1":"9719.7100"
    },{
     "d-1-c1":"01/09/2017",
     "p-1-c1":"4789.7300"
    },{
     "d-1-c1":"01/10/2017",
     "p-1-c1":"7448.3900"
    },{
     "d-1-c1":"01/11/2017",
     "p-1-c1":"6202.7200"
    },{
     "d-1-c1":"01/12/2017",
     "p-1-c1":"9274.0300"
    },{
     "d-1-c1":"01/01/2018"
    },{
     "d-1-c2":"01/07/2017"
    }
   ]
  });
```

```css
#chartdiv {
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
  <div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`labelFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#labelFunction) is definitely supported as you can see below.

```
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "bottom",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "labelFunction": function(value, valueText) {
      return "prefix:" + valueText;
    }
  }, {
    "minMaxMultiplier": 1.2,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "labelFunction": function(value, valueText) {
      return "prefix:" + valueText;
    }
  } ],
```

Demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  "theme": "light",
  "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true,
  },
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "y": 10,
    "x": 14,
    "value": 59,
    "y2": -5,
    "x2": -3,
    "value2": 44
  }, {
    "y": 5,
    "x": 3,
    "value": 50,
    "y2": -15,
    "x2": -8,
    "value2": 12
  }, {
    "y": -10,
    "x": 8,
    "value": 19,
    "y2": -4,
    "x2": 6,
    "value2": 35
  }, {
    "y": -6,
    "x": 5,
    "value": 65,
    "y2": -5,
    "x2": -6,
    "value2": 168
  }, {
    "y": 15,
    "x": -4,
    "value": 92,
    "y2": -10,
    "x2": -8,
    "value2": 102
  }, {
    "y": 13,
    "x": 1,
    "value": 8,
    "y2": -2,
    "x2": 0,
    "value2": 41
  }, {
    "y": 1,
    "x": 6,
    "value": 35,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2": -3,
    "value2": 16
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "bottom",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "labelFunction": function(value, valueText) {
      return "prefix:" + valueText;
    }
  }, {
    "minMaxMultiplier": 1.2,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "labelFunction": function(value, valueText) {
      return "prefix:" + valueText;
    }
  } ],
  "startDuration": 1.5,
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "x:<b>[[x]]</b> y:<b>[[y]]</b><br>value:<b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "circle",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "valueField": "value",
    "xField": "x",
    "yField": "y",
    "maxBulletSize": 100
  }, {
    "balloonText": "x:<b>[[x]]</b> y:<b>[[y]]</b><br>value:<b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "diamond",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "valueField": "value2",
    "xField": "x2",
    "yField": "y2",
    "maxBulletSize": 100
  } ]
} );
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

You can also use [`unit`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#unit) and [`unitPosition`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#unitPosition) if your custom labeling doesn't 
require any additional logic that you can leverage through `labelFunction`.

```
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "bottom",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "unit": "unit-prefix:",
    "unitPosition": "left"
  }, {
    "minMaxMultiplier": 1.2,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "unit": "unit-prefix:",
    "unitPosition": "left"
  } ],
```

Demo below.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  "theme": "light",
  "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true,
  },
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "y": 10,
    "x": 14,
    "value": 59,
    "y2": -5,
    "x2": -3,
    "value2": 44
  }, {
    "y": 5,
    "x": 3,
    "value": 50,
    "y2": -15,
    "x2": -8,
    "value2": 12
  }, {
    "y": -10,
    "x": 8,
    "value": 19,
    "y2": -4,
    "x2": 6,
    "value2": 35
  }, {
    "y": -6,
    "x": 5,
    "value": 65,
    "y2": -5,
    "x2": -6,
    "value2": 168
  }, {
    "y": 15,
    "x": -4,
    "value": 92,
    "y2": -10,
    "x2": -8,
    "value2": 102
  }, {
    "y": 13,
    "x": 1,
    "value": 8,
    "y2": -2,
    "x2": 0,
    "value2": 41
  }, {
    "y": 1,
    "x": 6,
    "value": 35,
    "y2": 0,
    "x2": -3,
    "value2": 16
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "bottom",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "unit": "unit-prefix:",
    "unitPosition": "left"
  }, {
    "minMaxMultiplier": 1.2,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "unit": "unit-prefix:",
    "unitPosition": "left"
  } ],
  "startDuration": 1.5,
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "x:<b>[[x]]</b> y:<b>[[y]]</b><br>value:<b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "circle",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "valueField": "value",
    "xField": "x",
    "yField": "y",
    "maxBulletSize": 100
  }, {
    "balloonText": "x:<b>[[x]]</b> y:<b>[[y]]</b><br>value:<b>[[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "diamond",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "valueField": "value2",
    "xField": "x2",
    "yField": "y2",
    "maxBulletSize": 100
  } ]
} );
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: I've updated my code with code snippet and yours. As you can see, prefix appear on X-Axis labels, not Y-Axis

Comment: If you look carefully at your code, both of your value axes are set to `position: "bottom"`, which are X axes. When a Y axis (`position: "left"` or `position: "right"`) is not defined, one will be created for you, which won't have a `labelFunction` attached to it. This is why you're not seeing your label function for a Y axis - you didn't define one. You need to define a value axis with `position: "left"` and set a `labelFunction` for it.